# Samsung G S9+(Android 8.1 API 26) using more memory than Motorola E2(Android 7.1.2 API 25) in the same Application

Tags: android, memory-management

Here are two screenshots I took for the memory usage in android studio:

Samsung Galaxy S9+ (Android 8.1 Stock API 26)
[image]

and

Motorola E2 (Android 7.1.2 Lineage OS 14.1 API 25)
[image]

The S9+ is using ~250mb when the Motorola E2 is only ~55mb

At this time the app is simply scrolling through a RecyclerView() where the S9+ displays 5 ViewHolders (each with one image ~20kb) vs the E2 displays 4 ViewHolders (same images as the S9+).

I am not sure why there is a huge difference in memory usage
Does it have to do anything with the version of Android?

Comment: Im not sure but S9+ has 6GB Ram whereas E2 has 1GB. As far as im concerned, the more ram you have the more ram you use, unless you have memory problems in which case Android will start managing it more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare RAM usage that way, not in a GCed language.  In Java and other GC languages, the GC is generally run only when the system thinks it needs it-  when it runs low.  If its not running low, it won't run.  That means a ton of objects that could be cleaned up are still on the heap, and will still count against you.  The only fair way to compare is to run a forced GC on each then compare.  Or better yet, to take a heap dump and only count objects that aren't eligible for cleanup.

Now there may be other reasons, such a s differences in implementations of some framework object caused a memory leak.  But most likely its just the explanation above.

Comment: That is interesting, won't that just push other apps that are in memory out and wont the other apps just have to restart because the system did not think it was necessary to GC.

Comment: Not if the system has sufficient ram. And if it doesn't the VM should detect that and garbage collect